# script to reduce and transfer images on drive and sheets does not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I developed a script that basically takes answers sent from the forms to the sheets, copies them from tab1 to tab2 inside the sheets, but one of those answers is an image and I found that if the script has more than 1 million pixels, I tried to work around it this of diversifying forms but always gives some error, sometimes the script completes but does not fulfill its function.

script1:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  // obter informações sobre a última linha inserida
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var colB = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).getValue();
  var colC = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();

  // redimensionar a imagem, se necessário
  var blob;
  try {
    blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(colC).getBlob();
    var size = blob.getBytes().length;
    if (size > 1000000) {
      blob = resizeImage(blob);
      var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
      colC = file.getUrl();
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Erro ao redimensionar imagem: " + e);
  }

  // inserir informações na planilha de evidências
  var evidencias = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("evidencias");
  evidencias.getRange("B7").setValue(colB);
  if (blob) {
    try {
      var image = evidencias.insertImage(blob, 2, 10, 8, 15);
      image.setHeight(240);
      image.setWidth(400);
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log("Erro ao inserir imagem na planilha: " + e);
    }
  }
}

function resizeImage(blob) {
  var MAX_WIDTH = 800;
  var MAX_HEIGHT = 600;

  var image = ImgApp.open(blob);
  var width = image.getWidth();
  var height = image.getHeight();

  if (width > MAX_WIDTH || height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
    if (width / MAX_WIDTH > height / MAX_HEIGHT) {
      height = Math.round(height * MAX_WIDTH / width);
      width = MAX_WIDTH;
    } else {
      width = Math.round(width * MAX_HEIGHT / height);
      height = MAX_HEIGHT;
    }
    image = image.doResize(width, height);
  }

  return image.getAs("image/jpeg");
}
```

attempt to simplify the script just for the image function:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formResponsesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("respostas");
  var evidenciasSheet = ss.getSheetByName("evidencias");
  
  // Obtém a última linha com dados na coluna C da aba "respostas"
  var lastRow = formResponsesSheet.getLastRow();
  var imgLink = formResponsesSheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  
  // Verifica se o link da imagem é válido
  var imgFile = DriveApp.getFileById(getFileIdFromUrl(imgLink));
  if (!imgFile) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Obtém a miniatura da imagem
  var thumbLink = imgFile.getThumbnailLink();
  if (thumbLink) {
    // Insere a miniatura na planilha "evidencias"
    var evidenciasRange = evidenciasSheet.getRange("B11:H25");
    evidenciasRange.clear();
    evidenciasRange.insertImage(thumbLink);
  } else {
    // Obtém a imagem original e redimensiona para altura de 500 pixels
    var imgBlob = imgFile.getBlob();
    var resizedBlob = resizeImage(imgBlob, 500);
    
    // Cria um novo arquivo na pasta "evidencias" e salva a imagem redimensionada nele
    var evidenciasFolder = getOrCreateFolder("evidencias", "1FtfoTwaj2_8pQBF4WN8YY8RLi-cWz2rPrxX7poYU0LcsDmf6U532DEbLJJXxZSUdSACqxqYB");
    var newImgFile = evidenciasFolder.createFile(resizedBlob);
    
    // Obtém o link da imagem redimensionada e insere na planilha "evidencias"
    var newImgLink = newImgFile.getUrl();
    var evidenciasRange = evidenciasSheet.getRange("B11:H25");
    evidenciasRange.clear();
    evidenciasRange.insertImage(newImgLink);
  }
}

function getFileIdFromUrl(url) {
  var regex = /[-\w]{25,}/;
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  return match[0];
}

function resizeImage(blob, maxHeight) {
  var image = ImagesService.getImage(blob);
  var width = image.getWidth();
  var height = image.getHeight();
  var ratio = height / width;
  
  if (height > maxHeight) {
    height = maxHeight;
    width = height / ratio;
  }
  
  var resizedImage = image.getScaledInstance(width, height);
  var resizedBlob = Utilities.newBlob(resizedImage, blob.getMimeType(), blob.getName());
  
  return resizedBlob;
}

function getOrCreateFolder(folderName, parentId) {
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentId);
  var folderIterator = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  
  if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    return folderIterator.next();
  } else {
    var newFolder = parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
    return newFolder;
  }
}
```

I expected that the script had taken the images from the drive and then had them reduced and attached to a range of merged cells (B11:H25) in the correct tab, however only the texts passed and the scripts failed in the part of the images.

Comment: I don't know what's going on here exactly, but have you tried converting your image to a data URL. Just an idea, not sure if it will work

Comment: ImgApp is undefined

Comment: @Cooper I downloaded the library for the API that should leave it, even so the script gives the error more when converting the image or inserting it

Comment: Can you minimize the code so that it only covers the problem you are asking  about.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `ImagesService`? Please add a reference to your question. Also specify how you added that service to your script project.

Comment: Would you please clarify... are files uploaded through the Form (in which case, the file is uploaded-and compressed-to Google Drive and Column C is a reference to the Google Drive URL) OR do users insert an external url for the image (in which case ColC is the external URL).